# Creating Record Page with Lightning App Builder

Tags: lightning, reporting, lightning-app-builder

I am trying to create a new record page using the lightning app builder for the Report object. I don't see Report in the dropdown of objects, but every other object is included. How can I make a record page for Reports?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can create lightning record pages for reports in the Lightning app builder. reports are built-in report builder instead of lightning app builder. [Reports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_report.htm) represent a report, a set of data that meets certain criteria, displayed in an organized way. Access is read-only. This object is available in API version 20.0 and later.